# Convert string array value to int when empty string value is possible

Tags: c#, null, int, arrays

I am having trouble converting a value in a string array to int since the value could possibly be null.

```
StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(filePath);
string currentLine = reader.ReadLine();
string[] splitLine = currentLine.Split(new char[] { '|' });
object.intValue = Convert.ToInt32(splitLine[10]);
```

This works great except for when splitLine[10] is null.
An error is thrown: `System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

Can someone provide me with some advice as to what the best approach in handling this would be?

Comment: Why don't you just ignore null values.  `String.Split` allows you to do that.

Comment: @Ramhound I don't necessarily know which values are going to be null and that would throw off the [countnumber] for other items I am trying to read by position in the string array.

Comment: The actual problem is that `splitLine[10]` is an empty string, not null. (`String.Split` never returns null elements.) `Convert.ToInt32` returns 0 if its argument is null; it throws `FormatException` if its argument is an empty string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (splitLine[10] != null)
    object.intValue = Convert.ToInt32(splitLine[10]);
else
    //do something else, if you want
```

You might also want to check that `splitLine.Length > 10` before getting `splitLine[10]`.

If you're reading something like a CSV file, and there's a chance it could be somewhat complicated, such as reading multiple values, it probably will make sense for you to use a connection string or other library-sorta-thing to read your file.  Get example connection strings from http://www.connectionstrings.com/textfile, using `Delimited(|)` to specify your delimiter, and then use them like `using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))`.  See the section in http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27802/Using-OleDb-to-Import-Text-Files-tab-CSV-custom about using the Jet engine.

Comment: this will fail if input is empty or WhiteSpace

Comment: @Tim S.  
Is there anyway to turn that into a generic method? I have about 6 other splitline[x] values that need to be handled the same way?

Comment: @Tim S. I combined your answer with comment:
if (splitLine[10] != "")
    object.intValue = Convert.ToInt32(splitLine[10]);

Comment: It might make sense for you to use a library designed for reading CSV-like files.  I'll edit my answer suggesting that.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use convert, it is better to use 
 `int.TryParse()`

e.g.

```
int val = 0;
if (int.TryParse(splitLine[10], out val))
   obj.intValue = val;
```

Comment: "Better"?  Some explanation on the differences would be good.

Comment: @TimS. TryParse will return `false` if the string is `null`, **or** not the correct format for an `int`. Convert will throw an exception in both cases.

Comment: `You would get an exception if splitLine.Length<11`

Comment: @Tim S It doesn't throw exception if the value is incorrect, Convert is good when you don't know if its a string or a boxed int in an object, etc.

Comment: @L.B yes, per his example I was assuming that is always the case, as he is asking how to do the conversion rather than how to handle the array itself

Comment: @NominSim By clicking the down-arrow

Comment: @L.B You mean "By 'someone that doesn't realize that this is a perfectly reasonable answer' clicking the down-arrow?", alright **why** did this perfectly reasonable answer get down-voted?

Comment: @SebastianPiu I cannot have the int value default to zero.  This is being used to keep track of scores and a 0 has a very specific meaning in that context if it is null or not set it needs to stay that way, only converting to int when it has an actual value.

Comment: My piece of code is not defaulting the value, it will only be assigned if the string value is a valid integer (TryParse will return false otherwise)

Comment: If TryParse returns false, it will still set the `out` parameter (`val`) to 0.  `out` parameters are (by definition) //always// set by the method.  In this case, `obj.intValue` will only be set if TryParse returned true.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a TryParse method:

```
int value;
if(Int32.TryParse(splitLine[10], out value))
{
    object.intValue = value;
} 
else 
{
    // Do something with incorrect parse value
}
```

Comment: @NonminSim That gives me the following error:
"A property, indexer or dynamic member access may not be passed as an out or ref parameter."

Answer (score 1):

if you're looking for the least code to write, try

```
object.intValue = Convert.ToInt32(splitLine[10] ?? "0");
```

If you want to preserve the meaning of the null in `splitLine[10]`, then you will need to change the type of `intValue` to be of type `Nullable<Int32>`, and then you can assign null to it. That's going to represent a lot more work, but that is the best way to use null values with value types like integers, regardless of how you get them.

Comment: Will that result in a value of zero if splitLine[10] is null?

Comment: @Baxter Yes, the [`??`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) operator is called the null-coalescing operator, the "0" is the default value the string parameter will take(and by extension your `object.intValue`) when `splitLine[10]` is null.

Comment: I don't agree with this answer, what is to differentiate the case when null gets coalesced to 0 from the case where the actual value of splitLine[10] is 0....

Comment: @EkoostikMartin I agree, especially since it seems likely that nulls in the OP's case should be ignored, not defaulted.

Comment: Okay, then by that reasoning, the OP needs to change the type of object.intValue to be a Nullable<Int32>. Lots of work. I doubt that was the point of the OP

Comment: I also agree this is being used for a score so 0 has a very real meaning in that context.  If it is null it needs to stay null or not set.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with

```
object.intValue = int.Parse(splitLine[10] ?? "<int value you want>");
```